# Поиск с подсказкой (автодополнением)

Tags: поиск, ajax, php, битрикс

Добрый день всем!

Коллеги, прошу подсказать какие-либо решение по реализации поиска с подсказкой (автодополнением) аля yandex или google на PHP и AJAX. Возможно есть какие-то наработанные библиотечные решения.

В дальнейшем планирую прикрутить его для организации фильтрации по стандартному каталогу товаров в битрикс, но сейчас сгодятся любые толковые наработки.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется такое реализовать совсем и не сложно.

1. Вешаем слушатель на ввод символов в поле поиска
2. каждый раз когда срабатывает ввод (ну или другие критерии - например прошло 200 мс после последнего ввода) отправляем введенные данные php скрипту
3. в php лезем в базу и смотрим что можем предложить
4. отправляем обратно и дорисовываем варианты.

Ну и на всякий случай ссылочки:

- http://www.linkexchanger.su/2011/700.html
- http://jelu.ru/2013/02/42.html

Answer (score 1):

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/
- http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/